# Can someone please translate this picture into english for me?

Tags: translation, character-identification

I got this picture by a friend a  days ago, but I have no idea what it says. It is not a good picture, but I hope someone on here will be able to translate at least parts of it for me. I do not know if it helps, but my friend says he got it in Beijing.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Large lettering:

> 約翰娜
>
> Johanna

First column to the right:

> 丙申年
>
> Year of [*bǐngshēn*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%99%E7%94%B3)

Far right column (best guess):

> 壯樂
>
> *Strong and Joyful* (probably an [art name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_name))

Bottom right seal:

> 張月英
>
> *Zhāng Yuèyīng*, probably the artist name

Left seal:

> 吉祥如意
>
> *Good fortune at one’s desire*

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The three big characters are 约翰娜. Probably a woman's name, Johanna.

The three small characters is 丙申年, which means the year 2016, or 2016 - (n * 60) (n could be any number).

The two small characters on the far right are a little hard. I guess 张东. It should be the name of author.

Comment: Thank you so much!